# Can I share charge pumps between multiple L6206 H-Bridge drivers?

Tags: h-bridge, charge-pump

I'm building a board to drive 8 separate motors, and I'm planning to use four [L6206 dual full H-Bridge drivers](https://www.st.com/en/motor-drivers/l6206.html).

The device uses N-channel MOSFETS all round and, from the datasheet:

> Using N-channel power MOS for the upper transistors in the bridge requires a gate drive
>   voltage above the power supply voltage. The bootstrapped (V BOOT ) supply is obtained
>   through an internal oscillator and few external components to realize a charge pump circuit
>   as shown in Figure 5. The oscillator output (VCP) is a square wave at 600 kHz (typical) with
>   10 V amplitude. Recommended values/part numbers for the charge pump circuit are shown
>   in Table 6.

So, fine, done that, all works. But if I have four of them, do I actually need four separate replicas of the charge pumps? My guess is that they're pulling the MOSFET gates up, which suggests minimal current draw on the *VBOOT* pin. Can I reasonably save some space/parts/assembly by making one circuit and sharing it? The datasheet doesn't specify characteristics for the *VBOOT* input as far as I can see.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frmeI4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or is this in the *"might work but stupid and high-risk"* category?

Comment: Unless you drive all the motors in unison, which means the identical PWM going to all drivers, you cannot parallel the boost circuits, which ride on the bridge output voltage. And even then, any fault or disconnection would expose your high side drivers to differential voltages they are not designed for. One fault, and all the drivers that share boost let the smoke out simultaneously.

Comment: @ChrisStratton diagram added

Comment: @Neil_UK Do the pumps ride on the bridge output voltage? I thought they ride on the \$V_s\$, main power input. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: @Neil_UK Sorry! had wrong part number. I mean L6206, NOT L6202. Edited, fixed.

Comment: Given that there is one boost voltage shared between both sides of the bridge, it would appear that it *does not* ride on the output, so that particular concern is moot.  Sharing between chips *might* be possible but it is unclear - the absence of any guidance on using an external source is unfortunate.  Overall it is relatively few components which should probably be implemented in a surface mount circuit close to the chip, so why not do as recommended?   (Pay careful attention to SMD capacitor voltage rating and especially actual performance at that voltage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

ST has an application note document AN1762 for this circuit, which seems to be a good read when designing something with it. It has this chapter that seems to be really interesting to you.

> **3.7 Sharing the Charge Pump Circuitry**
>
> If more than one device is used in the application, it's possible to use the charge pump from one L6205, L6206
>   or L6207 to supply the \$V_{BOOT}\$ pins of several ICs. The unused \$CP\$ pins on the slaved devices are left unconnected, as shown in Figure 10. A 100nF capacitor (C8) should be connected to the \$V_{BOOT}\$ pin of each device.
>   Supply voltage pins (\$V_S\$) of the devices sharing the charge pump must be connected together.
>
> The higher the number of devices sharing the same charge pump, the lower will be the differential voltage available for gate drive (\$V_{BOOT} - V_S\$), causing a higher \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ for the high side DMOS, so higher dissipating power. In this case it's recommended to omit the resistor on the \$CP\$ pin, obtaining a higher current capability of the charge pump circuitry.
>
> Better performance can also be obtained using a 33nF capacitor for C5 and using schottky diodes (for example BAT47 are recommended).
>
> Sharing the same charge pump circuitry for more than 3÷4 devices is not recommended, since it will reduce the \$V_{BOOT}\$ voltage increasing the high-side MOS on-resistance and thus power dissipation.

Comment: Well, this is the exact information I was looking for! Perfect, thank you!